# Восстановить диск после неудачного secure erase

Tags: диск, удаление

Сегодня я хотел просто стереть все данные с внешнего жёсткого диска прежде чем повторно использовать его. Думал для надёжности воспользоваться расширенным безопасным стиранием АТА. Так этот параметр называется в графическом интерфейсе. Но к сожалению, сразу же после начала этой операции, она завершилась ошибкой, а диск больше не читается. Переподключение не помогает. Похоже, он окирпичился от такого.

```
mymedia@barberry:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
fdisk: невозможно открыть /dev/sdb: Ошибка ввода/вывода
```

```
mymedia@barberry:~$ dmesg 
[186055.457700] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[186055.606620] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2329, bcdDevice= 1.00
[186055.606629] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[186055.606634] usb 1-2: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge
[186055.606639] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: JMicron
[186055.606643] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 17810DA14
[186055.608815] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[186055.609126] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 152d pid 2329: 8020
[186055.609256] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[186056.653925] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  MQ01ABF050       AM00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[186056.655022] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[186056.656467] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[186056.656827] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[186056.656834] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[186056.657170] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[186056.657181] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[186056.679800] scsi_io_completion_action: 4 callbacks suppressed
[186056.679818] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[186056.679832] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[186056.679842] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[186056.679854] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[186056.679859] print_req_error: 4 callbacks suppressed
[186056.679868] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[186056.679880] buffer_io_error: 3 callbacks suppressed
[186056.679885] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[186056.680552] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[186056.680566] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[186056.680577] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[186056.680588] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[186056.680597] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[186056.680611] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[186056.681272] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[186056.681282] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[186056.681293] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[186056.681303] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[186056.681313] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[186056.681324] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[186056.681355] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[186056.682434] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[186056.682446] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[186056.682457] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[186056.682467] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[186056.682477] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[186056.682488] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[186056.683078] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[186056.683089] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[186056.683101] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[186056.683111] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[186056.683120] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[186056.683130] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[186056.683748] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[186056.683756] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[186056.683767] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[186056.683776] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[186056.683784] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[186056.683792] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[186056.684391] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[186056.684400] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[186056.684410] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[186056.684419] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[186056.684427] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[186056.684436] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[186056.684464] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[186056.685041] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[186056.685049] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[186056.685059] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[186056.685068] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[186056.685075] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[186056.685084] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[186056.685742] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[186056.685750] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[186056.685759] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[186056.685766] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[186056.685773] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[186056.685780] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[186056.686383] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[186056.686391] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[186056.686399] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[186056.686408] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 08 00
[186056.686414] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 24 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[186056.686422] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3, async page read
[186056.687610]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[186056.689748] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[186066.365445] scsi_io_completion_action: 4 callbacks suppressed
[186066.365461] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[186066.365467] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[186066.365471] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[186066.365477] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[186066.365479] print_req_error: 4 callbacks suppressed
[186066.365483] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[186066.365490] buffer_io_error: 3 callbacks suppressed
[186066.365493] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[186066.366003] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[186066.366006] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[186066.366011] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[186066.366015] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[186066.366019] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[186066.366023] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[186066.366535] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[186066.366537] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[186066.366540] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[186066.366542] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[186066.366545] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[186066.366547] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
```

```
mymedia@barberry:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-42-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ01ABF...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050
Serial Number:    178QPDA1T
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 782e02099
Firmware Version: AM001J
User Capacity:    500 107 862 016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Aug 15 11:51:05 2020 MSK
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 124) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       1380
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5119
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   063   063   000    Old_age   Always       -       15057
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   201   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1363
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3396
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       165
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   081   081   000    Old_age   Always       -       195595
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       32 (Min/Max 13/57)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   067   067   000    Old_age   Always       -       13360
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       192
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 4
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 4 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15056 hours (627 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in standby mode.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 51 00 00 00 00 a0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  f4 00 01 00 00 00 a0 00      00:07:53.907  SECURITY ERASE UNIT
  f3 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:07:53.906  SECURITY ERASE PREPARE
  ec 00 01 00 00 00 a0 00      00:07:53.901  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  f2 00 01 00 00 00 a0 00      00:07:23.856  SECURITY UNLOCK
  e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:04:44.769  CHECK POWER MODE

Error 3 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15056 hours (627 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in standby mode.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 51 00 00 00 00 a0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  f2 00 01 00 00 00 a0 00      00:07:23.856  SECURITY UNLOCK
  e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:04:44.769  CHECK POWER MODE
  f2 00 01 00 00 00 a0 00      00:04:28.799  SECURITY UNLOCK
  f2 00 01 00 00 00 a0 00      00:04:17.548  SECURITY UNLOCK
  b0 d1 01 01 4f c2 a0 00      00:03:29.579  SMART READ ATTRIBUTE THRESHOLDS [OBS-4]

Error 2 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15056 hours (627 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 51 00 00 00 00 a0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  f2 00 01 00 00 00 a0 00      00:04:28.799  SECURITY UNLOCK
  f2 00 01 00 00 00 a0 00      00:04:17.548  SECURITY UNLOCK
  b0 d1 01 01 4f c2 a0 00      00:03:29.579  SMART READ ATTRIBUTE THRESHOLDS [OBS-4]
  b0 d0 01 00 4f c2 a0 00      00:03:27.838  SMART READ DATA
  ec 00 01 00 00 00 a0 00      00:03:27.824  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15056 hours (627 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in standby mode.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 51 00 00 00 00 a0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  f2 00 01 00 00 00 a0 00      00:04:17.548  SECURITY UNLOCK
  b0 d1 01 01 4f c2 a0 00      00:03:29.579  SMART READ ATTRIBUTE THRESHOLDS [OBS-4]
  b0 d0 01 00 4f c2 a0 00      00:03:27.838  SMART READ DATA
  ec 00 01 00 00 00 a0 00      00:03:27.824  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 01 00 00 00 a0 00      00:02:12.694  IDENTIFY DEVICE

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15057         -
# 2  Short captive       Completed without error       00%     15057         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Как восстановить такое? Возможно ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выяснилось, что такое безопасное стирание происходит через установку временного пароля с последующим сбросом этого пароля. Оказывается, утилита GNOME Диски, которую я использовал для работы с накопителем, основана UDisks, где используемый пароль жёстко [зашит в коде](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-disk-utility/-/issues/93#note_300847) — четыре буквы икс, `xxxx`. Соответственно, зная его, возможно сбросить самостоятельно через терминал. До и после операции диск придётся переподключить.

```
sudo hdparm --security-unlock xxxx /dev/sdb
sudo hdparm --security-disable xxxx /dev/sdb
```

В конце концов, после успешной разблокировки вывод информации о диске будет примерно такой как ниже. В секции Security должно быть "not enabled", "not locked".

```
mymedia@barberry:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb
ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050                      
    Serial Number:      178QPDA1T
    Firmware Revision:  AM001J  
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Supported: 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 8
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:   976773168
The running kernel lacks CONFIG_IDE_TASK_IOCTL support for this device.
READ_LOG_EXT(0,0) failed: Invalid argument
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:      476940 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:      500107 MBytes (500 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = 8192 KBytes
    Form Factor: 2.5 inch
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5400
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
    Advanced power management level: 1
    DMA: sdma0 sdma1 sdma2 mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 *udma5 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    NOP cmd
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Advanced Power Management feature set
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
       *    IDLE_IMMEDIATE with UNLOAD
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Host-initiated interface power management
       *    Phy event counters
       *    Idle-Unload when NCQ is active
       *    Host automatic Partial to Slumber transitions
       *    Device automatic Partial to Slumber transitions
       *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
            DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
            Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Software settings preservation
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
       *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    116min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 116min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000039782e02099
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 000039
    Unique ID   : 782e02099
Checksum: correct
```

Жалко, что никаких более дружественных подсказок GNU/Linux Ubuntu MATE не выдаёт. Но надеюсь, моё решение будет ещё кому-нибудь полезно.